# Use string to select column per row in dplyr (or base R)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column filled with other column names. I want get the value in each of the column names.

```
# three columns with values and one "key" column
library(dplyr)
data = data.frame(
  x = runif(10),
  y = runif(10),
  z = runif(10),
  key = sample(c('x', 'y', 'z'), 10, replace=TRUE)
)

# now get the value named in 'key'
data = data %>% mutate(value = VALUE_AT_COLUMN(key))
```

I'm pretty sure the answer has something to do with the lazy eval version of mutate, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could, also, try `data[c("x", "y", "z")][cbind(seq_len(nrow(data)), match(data$key, names(data)))]` to avoid grouping by every row (with the, probably lower, cost of an intermediate conversion to "matrix").

Comment: @alexis_laz I'd prefer a more extensible approach that doesn't require listing every column.

Comment: Depending on how your columns are ordered, there should be many ways to programmaticaly extract the needed ones; `data[1:3]`, `data[unique(data$key)]`, `data[!names(data) %in% "key"]` etc

Comment: So, I am confused now.  You don't want a dplyr solution, anymore??

Comment: A dplyr solution would be ideal, but I'm generally trying to avoid needing yet another data frame library. So base R is good too. Sorry if that was confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a Base R solution:

```
data$value = diag(as.matrix(data[,data$key]))
```

Comment: Interesting, though I guess this is not memory efficient at all.

Comment: Nope! There may be a more memory efficient base method, but if you're going for performance then you should look to `data.table` or `dplyr`.  If you don't want to load more packages and your data isn't massive, then this will work.

Answer (score 6):

We can try `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data)`), grouped by the sequence of rows, we use `.SD` to subset the columns specified by 'key'.

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(data)[,  .SD[, key[[1L]], with=FALSE] ,1:nrow(data)]
```

Or another option is `get` after converting the 'key' to `character` class (as it `factor`) after grouping by sequence of rows as in the previous case.

```
 setDT(data)[, get(as.character(key)), 1:nrow(data)]
```

---

Here is one option with `do`

```
 library(dplyr)
 data %>% 
    group_by(rn = row_number()) %>%
    do(data.frame(., value= .[[.$key]]))
```

Comment: I can do this using other libraries, but I'm trying to avoid needing to import yet another data frame library

Comment: @sharoz It is possible with `dplyr` using `do`,

Comment: Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: @sharoz Posted the `do` option.

Answer (score 5):

For a memory efficient and fast solution, you should update your original data.table by performing a join as follows:

```
data[.(key2 = unique(key)), val := get(key2), on=c(key="key2"), by=.EACHI][]
```

For each `key2` the matching rows in `data$key` are calculated. Those rows are updated with the values from the column that is contained in `key2`. For example, `key2="x"` matches with rows `1,2,6,8,10`. The corresponding values of `data$x` are `data$x[c(1,2,6,8,10)]`. `by=.EACHI` ensures the expression `get(key2)` is executed for each value of `key2`.

Since this operation is performed only on unique values it should be considerably faster than running it row-wise. And since the data.table is updated by reference, it should be quite memory efficient (and that contributes to speed as well).

Answer (score 4):

It definitely feels like there should be a base R solution to this, but the best I could do was with `tidyr`, to first transform the data to wide form, then filter for just those observations that match the desired key.

```
data %>%
  add_rownames("index") %>%
  gather(var, value, -index, -key) %>%
  filter(key == var)
```

---

A base R solution that almost works:

```
data[cbind(seq_along(data$key), data$key)]
```

For the data given, it does works, but because it uses a matrix, it has two serious problems.  One is that the order of the factor matters, because it's just coercing that out, and selecting columns by factor level, not by the column name.  The other is that the resulting output is a `character`, not a `numeric`, because in the conversion to a matrix, the type `character` is chosen because of the `key` column.  The key problem is that there is no `data.frame` analog to the matrix behavior of

> When indexing arrays by '[' a single argument 'i' can be a matrix with as many columns as there are dimensions of 'x'; the result is then a vector with elements corresponding to the sets of indices in each row of 'i'.

Given these problems, I would probably go with the `tidyr` solution, since the fact that the columns are variably selectable means that they probably represent different observations for the same observable unit.